# Why is django running from virtualenv unable to write to that path?

Tags: python, linux, django, security, virtualenv

Our client has a web application running a Django instance from virtualenv on a Ubuntu server. We did a security audit for that service and found a path traversal vulnerability in a file upload form that could allow the attacker to write arbitrary files in the django user owned paths. Example:

A parameter "Import Name" is supplied with value

```
../some/path/to/create
```

Then the form file field is supplied with arbitary `filename` and the correct file contents

The application then does

```
try:
    path = os.path.join(DEFAULT_UPLOAD_DIR, <Import Name>)
    os.mkdir(path)
    ...
    with open(os.path.join(path, <Filename From Form>)) as upload_file:
        upload_file.write(<File Contents>)
    ...
```

The unsafe `os.path.join` allows the attacker to walk up in the directory tree and upload to other directories than the `DEFAULT_UPLOAD_DIR`. So basically if the attacker is able to find a path that doesn't yet exist on the server he's able to create that folder avoiding the failure of `os.mkdir()` in the `try...except` and the file is uploaded there.

Now this translates to a real exploit if the attacker is able to write to

```
../virtualenvs/<env name>/lib/python2.7/
```

Since e.g Django modules are loaded from the subdirectory `site-packages` within the virtualenv python directory and pythonpath tells us whatever is directly under `lib/python2.7` gets loaded first, essentially the module loading order allows the attacker to 'overwrite' a module and ensure their code is run on import.

We did a proof-of-concept penetration test and wrote to

`../virtualenvs/somepath/__init__.py`

Which succeeded but for some reason we are unable to write to

`../virtualenvs/<actual env name>/`

Which is strange cause the permissions are exactly the same as with `somepath` and owner / group is in both cases the Django user. Enabling the virtualenv for the Django user and going to the python shell it allows me to do the write so it seems weird that it can't when called from the vulnerable form view.

**The question is:** Is there something special about the virtualenv path from which the Django instance is running that makes it unable to write to that path? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your test is running as the same user as the django instance? How is that instance started? Next thing I'd check: Does the web server have SELinux enabled?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Why aren't you using django's built in file upload mechanism in the first place? Why are you running django as a system user? How exactly are you running it anyway (gunicorn, uwsgi etc)?

Comment: I think the question is as clear as it can be. Why are you interested to know why our CLIENT is not using the django's built in file upload mechanism? WHY is not a relevant question to this issue. Also, I don't think I ever said it's running as system user. But yeah anyway, gunicorn is being used.